# For Loop different type on how to code

Tags: java, for-loop

Hi can somebody tell me the difference between this to for loops..

```
int y = 3;
int sif [] = new int [150];
for(int a= 0;a<sif.length;a = a + y){
sif[a]=a;
y++;
}
```

and this one:

```
int y = 3;
int sif [] = new int [150];
for(int a= 0;a<sif.length;a = a + y){
sif[a]=a;
}
y++;
```

is there a difference can somebody explain this...

Comment: ... One of them increments `y` inside the loop. The other doesn't.

Comment: A good exercise would be to step through the code in the debugger, and watch the variable values change.

Comment: If your code was indented properly, the difference would be obvious. If you executed both and printed the sif array, it would be obvious as well.

Comment: first loop finishes much more quickly

Answer (score 1):

The last two lines should clue you in:

one has `y++` before the closing brace, and the other has it after. In  the first, `y` will be incremented each time the loop runs, right before `a=a+y` is executed. In the second, `y` will be incremented after the loop *ends*.

Comment: ok then how about adding while loop to the top of the for loop so that the whole thing will loop from the start but this time the value of y is 3 is that possible??

Comment: @IvanLorenzo Yes, but why bother with that? Just assign 3 to y with `y=3`.

Comment: yeah but you see what im trying to do in that program is make it count by 2's till it reached its mark and after that it start the count by 3's till hitting the mark the first one is suppose to show even numbers 2 4 6 8 in the next one 3 6 9...something like that

Comment: @IvanLorenzo Yes, just use `y=3` in the second loop. I would strongly recommend trying to "imagine" what this program will do.'

Answer (score 1):

the line `y++` in the first loop sample would **increment the `y` variable in every iteration of the loop block**. For the second loop sample, `y` would only be incremented after the entire for loop is processed, **in this case only once**, because `y++` is outside the for-loop block.